# Change GVs at runtime on tibco

Tags: tibco

I need to change the value of a global Variable while the engine its running, does anybody know how to do it? (javacode or whatever) the idea its to integrate the change as part of a process.

What  if i want to do it only in test mode? i have my unitary test on the same project that the functional code, so i want to ensure myself that no tests GV�s are activated before start, to do that withaout changing any ear i want to integrate that on the unitary test process so, i start on tester, the process change the GV�s as need itself, and then it delete the VG so i have not to concern about that.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I never found it... and historically ended up making my own properties on the side. I will be interested to see the answers...

Comment: Doesn´t see that we gonna´have much answers, even more if we are not interested on... "Gv its not for that..." answers. By the way, the best i have found for now is to run the tester with a config file, but i prefer to do exactly the same functionallity but as part of a process.

Answer (score 0):

Trough standard palette can't alter GV at runtime.

If you want to alter configuration at runtime you can use shared variables and have a poller process to reload them (e.g. on file change or every 5 min)